# Is there a German word for "reluctance to embark on final chapter/phase due to enjoyment thus far"

Tags: compound

I have been reading a book and really enjoying it and I found myself reluctant to start the last chapter because I didn't want the experience to be over.  I wondered whether there is a word for this in German.  Perhaps something more general which could apply to other situations too, such as:

- not wanting to start the final episode in a wonderful TV series
- not wanting to go to bed on the last night of a lovely holiday
- avoiding eating the last chocolate in a tasty variety box

Or can one simply build the word somehow?

Comment: Is there a word for it in English? If there is I don't know it. Maybe some other language? While German does allow you to be more, let's say, creative with vocabulary than other languages, it's not really true that there's a word for every imaginable concept or condition.

Comment: Indeed @RDBury I'm not aware of an English word for this specific situation, I was wondering just in case, because you sometimes hear of delightful words or phrases in other languages which require a whole sentence to describe in English - I think German in particular has that reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a single German word that specifically means reluctance to start the final chapter/phase due to enjoyment thus far.

However, you could use the term ***"Endzeitangst"*** to describe the general feeling of not wanting something enjoyable to end. Another option is ***"Abschiedsschmerz"***, which means "farewell pain/sorrow".

You could probably make up your own word by combining "Genuss" (enjoyment) and "Ende" (end) to create "Genussende", but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single word. You just say it in German like you described the action, for example
"Ich konnte das letzte Kapitel nicht lesen, weil ich nicht wollte, dass das Buch vorbei ist." / " ... weil ich sonst aus der Traumwelt des Buches gerissen würde."
or
"Ich habe das letzte Stück Schokolade nicht gegessen, weil ich nicht wollte, dass der Genuss vorbei ist."